# Theoretical mechanics - Inverse Kinematicss

Tags: kinematics, robotics

On theoretical mechanics essay at the university, I have stumbled in the issue below:

Given $\textbf{u}^T \textbf{D}(\mathbf{\theta}, \alpha)\textbf{v}(\textbf{d}) = \textbf{m}(\textbf{d})$, find out if it is possible to find a funciont $f: \textbf{p} \rightarrow \textbf{q}$, for $\textbf{q}^T = [\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3]$ and $\textbf{p}^T = [\textbf{d}^T, \alpha]$, $\textbf{d}^T = [x, y]$ and find it, if so. The equations below give the structure of $\textbf{D}(\mathbf{\theta}, \alpha)$ and $\textbf{v}(d)$.

\begin{equation}
v(d) =
\begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{v}_1(\textbf{d}) \\
\textbf{v}_2(\textbf{d}) \\
\textbf{v}_3(\textbf{d})\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\textbf{v}_i(d) =
\begin{bmatrix}
\textbf{d} - d_0^1 \\
\textbf{d} - d_0^2 \\
\textbf{d} - d_0^3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:D}
\textbf{D}(\mathbf{\theta}, \alpha) = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{D_1}(\mathbf{\theta_1}, \alpha) & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \mathbf{D_2}(\mathbf{\theta_2}, \alpha) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \mathbf{D_3}(\mathbf{\theta_3}, \alpha) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:Di}
\mathbf{D_i}(\mathbf{\theta_i}, \alpha) = \begin{bmatrix}
-\mathbf{R}(\theta_i + \beta_i) & -\mathbf{R}(\theta_i + \alpha + \beta_i)\\
\mathbf{R}(\alpha) & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:R}
\mathbf{R}(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)\\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

A priori, the equation has 6 possible solutions for given feasible and reachable $\mathbf{p}$. For the sake of curiosity, the solutions comes for the position of [this mechanism](https://www.rtm.tu-darmstadt.de/fg_rtm/rtm_mitarbeiter_ehemalige/mitarbeiterseiten_ehemalige/rtm_mitarbeiter_schmitt_daniel/rtm_mitarbeiter_labisch_daniel_home.de.jsp).

If the problem is ill-formed or lacks information, make me aware of it. Furthermore, if a numerical is better suited for this case, explain the manners to reach $\textbf{ALL}$ solutions of the problem.

I thank in advance for the attention and given effort.

Best regards, Bruno.